# Retrieving a fingerprint Blob is Crashing the app at run time, SQLITE for Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**The following errors have been logged**

at com.github.omadahealth.lollipin.DatabaseHelper.userFP1(DatabaseHelper.java:400)
        at com.magtouch.app.gateopen$22.onUpCharSuccess(gateopen.java:777)
        at android_serialport_api.AsyncFingerprint.handleMessage(AsyncFingerprint.java:126)

**Database Function**

```
public byte[] userFP1(int userID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[]{FINGER_PRINT1}, USER_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userID)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor.getBlob (10  );

    }
```

**code calling the database**

```
    if(db.userFP1 (i)!=null){
                        System.arraycopy( db.userFP1 ( i ), 0, tmp, 0, 256);
                        if(FPMatch.getInstance().MatchTemplate(model,tmp)>60){
                            tvFpStatus.setText(getString( R.string.txt_fpmatchok));
                            break;
                        }
Section pointed by the error from (AsyncFingerprint.java:126)
if (msg.obj != null) {
                        onUpCharListener.onUpCharSuccess((byte[]) msg.obj);
                    } else {
                        onUpCharListener.onUpCharFail();
                    }
```

Comment: You didn't include the part of the log where it says what the actual exception is. Also, why did you put `return cursor.getBlob (10);` outside of the `if (cursor != null`? If the cursor is null then you cannot call `getBlob`.

Comment: I have used zero still  it did work for me, do when i did put 10 was just trying my luck

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me

```
public byte[] userFP1(int userID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase ();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[]{FINGER_PRINT1}, USER_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userID)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            byte[] imgByte = cursor.getBlob(0);
            cursor.close();
            return imgByte;
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```